# SQLite : WAL mode not behaving as persistent

Tags: sqlite

I have sqlite version 3.7.17 and using sqlite3 terminal tool, I ran

```
PRAGMA journal_mode = WAL;
```

and it returns `wal`.

I have a process which sync USB and creates database. I inserted the USB, process starts and I can still see the `-journal` files. I am nowhere setting it back to `DELETE` mode.
Since WAL is sticky, my DB should be built in WAL mode for every next time but I am not observing this behaviour? What can be the problem or I am understanding the process wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WAL mode settings applies to the database.

When you create a new database, you get the default journal mode for that (unless you execute the PRAGMA for that DB, too).